# How does binding two slider XAML control values together work?

Tags: c#, xaml

I made a simple blank metro store app in VS2012 and added two sliders in a StackPanel, like this:

```
<StackPanel>
     <Slider Name="sliderTest1" Value="{Binding ElementName=sliderTest2, Path=Value}" />
     <Slider Name="sliderTest2" Value="{Binding ElementName=sliderTest1, Path=Value}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I expected that sliding either slider would cause them both to move. And that's true as long as I've only touched one slider. As soon as I touch the other slider, they no longer move together.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `Mode=TwoWay` to the bindings -- that will cause each to update the other.

```
<Slider Name="sliderTest1" 
    Value="{Binding ElementName=sliderTest2, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Ah, that did the trick. I'm reading about Xaml controls and bindings in a Charles Petzold book, but haven't gotten to anything about Mode. Thanks!

Comment: both sliders can not have two way binding - that will cause infinite recursion and a stackoverflow exception

Comment: @nocturns2 good point ... I guess to do it right, you'd really need a view model property that both sliders bind to.

Comment: Actually, I did what @dbaseman suggested, adding Mode=TwoWay to both sliders. The code seems to work fine. I'm going to keep going through my book and see if I can understand WHY the original behavior is the way it is. It seems weird that without Mode=TwoWay, it works when I've only moved one slider, but as soon as I click the other, the binding seems to break.

Comment: @casper I think I can tell you why the binding breaks -- basically, the `Value` (a dependency property) is set initially as bound to a source (the other slider's Value).  But when you touch the slider in the UI, the `Value` then gets reset to a constant value; hence, no more binding.